# Using rive animation in flutter uses lots of Graphics memory

Tags: flutter, rive

I tried to develop an application and was warming up all the rives files on app launch so that the rive animations could play properly. But during the gameplay, as you see more and more rive animation it was consuming more graphics memory (checked using the Android profile tool).
So after going through a lot of docs I found the possible fix.
Adding FlareCache.doesPrune = false;

Comment: FlareCache.doesPrune = false;
Use this after warming up your rive files